# Generate regex from character range

Tags: regex, vba

I have a list of names, and I use regular expressions to filter that list. 
Let's say my list looks like this:

- Alice
- Anna
- Bob
- Jane
- John
- Frank
- Peter

Now I only want the names in the range `A-D`, so I use the regex `^[A-D].*` and get *Alice, Anna, Bob*.

This was easy, but the regex gets more complicated when I chose a more specific range, like `A-Jen` --> `^([A-I].*|J([a-d]|[a-e][a-n]).*)`

Now i get *Alice, Anna, Bob, Jane*.

And it gets even harder, e.g.

`Abc-Def` --> `^((A([b-z][c-z].*|[c-z].*))|[B-C].*|D([a-d]|[a-e][a-f]).*)`

So basically I'm looking for a way to generate these regular expressions according to the character range.  I tried to make a VBA script to do the job, but unfortunately I couldn't do it. That's why I'm asking you guys for help :)

Does anyone have an idea how I could generate these expressions? 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

PS: English is not my native language, but I hope you understand my question :)

Comment: What have you tried with your VBA script?  Why isn't it working?  At first glance, it looks like you have the idea of how to take the requirement and turn it into the regex, so what is the issue you are having turning it into code?

Comment: Why use regex at all? Why not sort the list?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this list is part of an application, and it uses regex to filter the names, so i can't change that. That's why I actually need to generate the regular expressions. There is no other way.
I didn't post my VBA approach, because I didn't manage to do anything really. I know how to manually write the regex, I just don't know how to create a script or whatever that does what I need.

Comment: Look, this is a tall order. Nobody's going to do it for you (at least not for free). You're going to have to try something yourself — and ask about specific problems you run into along the way. For that we can help. Hint: this looks like a recursive task. The pattern is `(A(###)|[B-C].*|D(###).*` where `###` itself has a similar structure.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative, much simpler approach:

An Excel formula

```
=AND($A5>=$B$1,$A5<=$B$2)
```

or an equivalent VBA user-defined function

```
Function IsAlphabeticallyBetween(ByVal strName As String, _
    ByVal lo As String, ByVal hi As String) As Boolean

    IsAlphabeticallyBetween = strName >= lo And strName <= hi

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This would work in excel of course, but my list   is not in excel (forgot to mention this, sorry). The list is part of an application that only accepts regex to filter the names. So I actually need to generate the regex.

Comment: Why don't you just extract all names A-Z and filter them yourself using the above VBA function? Using Regex to sort alphabetically is like... like... I'm struggling to find a good metaphor for using a super complex approach to do something really simple.

Comment: I don't want to extract the names, the application just needs regex to do stuff. I can't really explain it, but it also doesn't matter to you :). All I want to know is how I can generate the regex.